# Select column from another table's row and data from another table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to select column name from one table's row and row from another table column?

Let's  say `ColumnTable` has a column `ColumnOfTbl1`. Now `ColumnOfTbl1` has column name defined in row of `ColumnTable`'s column name `ColumnTbl1`. I have to pick data from `ColumnOfTbl1` and column name from `ColumnTable`'s column.

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all - can you provide a sample? What would your table and another table look like, what data would be stored in them, and what are you trying to do with that data??

Comment: select (select columnname from columnlist where coltrue = 'true') from columndata where colid < 100

Comment: @user3252143 nobody is gone steal you code here, just post your code. People are very willing to help, but you have to assist them.

Comment: thanks. But My question is very simple. I simply want to pickup column from other table's row and data related to that column from another table. Pivot may be used to achieve answer of this problem. But how?